# How to have web-fragment.xml on Tomcat 6

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, web.xml

I want to share some definitions from the *web.xml* in many WAR archives. I don't want to duplicate lines in many *web.xml*.
So I created Maven modules with dependencies. But now I want to share *web.xml*. I see *web-fragment.xml* works in Tomcat 7 with Servlet 3.0, but is there a solution that works in Tomcat 6?

I try to have mywebapp/WEB-INF/lib/jar/META-INF/web-fragment.xml in Tomcat 6 but nothing appends.
Is there a way to share web.xml in Tomcat 6?

I'm using Spring 3, JSPX.

Answer (score 2):

because tomcat6 doesn't implement servlet 3.0 specs.
So AFAIK no way :-)

Comment: Ok but is there a way to share web.xml in Tomcat 6?

Answer (score 0):

very hackish but change the default web.xml in $CATALINA_HOME/conf/web.xml